# Module not found - how to install a package in a Django + poetry project?

Tags: python, django

This is such a basic question, I'm sorry. I installed [django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley) with poetry (`poetry add django-parsley`). It's clearly installed in my `pyproject.toml` file.

In my django project files, in `forms.py`, I have a line of code that imports a module from `parsley`: `from parsley.decorators import parsleyfy`

However, when I try to run `python manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
   from parsley.decorators import parsleyfy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsley'
```

I also tried adding 'parsley' to my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. That gives me this error (which is maybe due to not adding it globally with `pip install`?):

```
...some more errors...
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsley'
```

What do I need to do to be able to import it in a python file in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's actually a VSCode issue - normally, VSCode automatically identifies the right virtual environment for the project (in this case, Poetry's default auto-created project-specific venv).

However, in this project, it didn't switch over. To fix, I ran the `Python: Select Interpreter` command and switched the venv over to the right project. It then recognized the site-packages folder and was able to import normally.